# JavaFX how to cancel ComboBox selection change?

Tags: java, javafx, combobox

Here is the demo code:

```java
public class ComboBoxTest extends Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Application.launch(ComboBoxTest.class);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        ComboBox<String> comboBox = new ComboBox<>();
        comboBox.getItems().addAll("option1", "option2", "option3");
        comboBox.getSelectionModel().select(0);

        comboBox.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty().addListener(
            (_ob, _old, _new) -> {
                if (!isValidChange(_old, _new)) {
                    // ERROR: try to cancel change and get StackOverflowError
                    comboBox.getSelectionModel().select(_old);
                }
        });

        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(
                new BorderPane(comboBox), 300, 200));
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    private static boolean isValidChange(String _old, String _new) {
        // return false;
        return !_old.equals("option1");
    }
}
```

When changing selection of `comboBox`, it centainly throws `StackOverFlowError`, I know the reason why (the `ChangeListener` object is triggered again and again), but what I don't know is how to correctly **"cancel"** this selection change operation.

---

**Update:**

Sorry @fabian I wrote a bad example here, let me change it a little bit:

```
private static boolean isValidChange(String _old, String _new) {
    return !_old.equals("option1");
}
```

It works now, the `comboBox` value cannot be changed. However I get a strange `IndexOutOfBoundsException` here, while there is no line of my code in the stack trace:

```
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.ReadOnlyUnbackedObservableList.subList(ReadOnlyUnbackedObservableList.java:136)
    at javafx.collections.ListChangeListener$Change.getAddedSubList(ListChangeListener.java:242)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.ListViewBehavior.lambda$new$177(ListViewBehavior.java:269)
    at javafx.collections.WeakListChangeListener.onChanged(WeakListChangeListener.java:88)
    at com.sun.javafx.collections.ListListenerHelper$Generic.fireValueChangedEvent(ListListenerHelper.java:329)
    at com.sun.javafx.collections.ListListenerHelper.fireValueChangedEvent(ListListenerHelper.java:73)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.ReadOnlyUnbackedObservableList.callObservers(ReadOnlyUnbackedObservableList.java:75)
    at javafx.scene.control.MultipleSelectionModelBase.clearAndSelect(MultipleSelectionModelBase.java:378)
    at javafx.scene.control.ListView$ListViewBitSetSelectionModel.clearAndSelect(ListView.java:1403)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.CellBehaviorBase.simpleSelect(CellBehaviorBase.java:256)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.CellBehaviorBase.doSelect(CellBehaviorBase.java:220)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.CellBehaviorBase.mousePressed(CellBehaviorBase.java:150)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.BehaviorSkinBase$1.handle(BehaviorSkinBase.java:95)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.BehaviorSkinBase$1.handle(BehaviorSkinBase.java:89)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler$NormalEventHandlerRecord.handleBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:218)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:80)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:54)
    at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Scene.java:3757)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.access$1500(Scene.java:3485)
    at javafx.scene.Scene.impl_processMouseEvent(Scene.java:1762)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerListener.mouseEvent(Scene.java:2494)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:380)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:294)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.lambda$handleMouseEvent$354(GlassViewEventHandler.java:416)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.runWithoutRenderLock(QuantumToolkit.java:389)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.handleMouseEvent(GlassViewEventHandler.java:415)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.View.handleMouseEvent(View.java:555)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.View.notifyMouse(View.java:937)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$148(WinApplication.java:191)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Is this a bug of JavaFX?

Comment: After update: The only thing you have to do is to wrap `comboBox.getSelectionModel().select(_old);` into a `Platform.runLater(...)` block like `Platform.runLater(() -> comboBox.getSelectionModel().select(_old));`

Comment: @DVarga It works now, thanks

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 issues here.

1. A change from value `a` to value `b` is not valid, but also a change from `b` to `a` is invalid. Therefore when the value is changed the listener undos the change which leads to another change event that the listener tries to undo, which again the listener tries to undo, ...
2. You modify the selection model. However the selection model relies on the selection being unchanged.

To fix these issues introduce a `ChangeListener` that "knows when it's vetoing a change" and runs the change after the change event was handled using `Platform.runLater`:

```
public abstract class VetoListener<T> implements ChangeListener<T> {

    private final SelectionModel<T> selectionModel;
    private boolean changing = false;

    public VetoListener(SelectionModel<T> selectionModel) {
        if (selectionModel == null) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException();
        }
        this.selectionModel = selectionModel;
    }

    @Override
    public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends T> observable, T oldValue, T newValue) {
        if (!changing && isInvalidChange(oldValue, newValue)) {
            changing = true;
            Platform.runLater(() -> {
                selectionModel.select(oldValue);
                changing = false;
            });
        }
    }

    protected abstract boolean isInvalidChange(T oldValue, T newValue);

}
```

The following code will prevent changes from `"A"` to `"B"` and from `"B"` to `"C"`:

```
@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    ComboBox<String> combo = new ComboBox<>(FXCollections.observableArrayList("A", "B", "C"));

    combo.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty().addListener(new VetoListener<String>(combo.getSelectionModel()) {

        @Override
        protected boolean isInvalidChange(String oldValue, String newValue) {
            return oldValue != null && newValue != null
                    && !oldValue.isEmpty()
                    && !newValue.isEmpty()
                    && oldValue.charAt(0)+1 == newValue.charAt(0);
        }

    });

    Scene scene = new Scene(combo);

    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
}
```

Comment: Thanks! you solved my `StackOverflowError` issue, but there is a new problem now and I updated my post.