# How to validate data before allowing selection change?

Tags: java, javafx

In my application, there I have two sections: list of data and a section for editing the details of that data. The user selects an item from a `ListView` or `TableView` and that item's properties appear and are editable on the right side of the window. *The MCVE below will demonstrate this.*

What I need to be able to do is validate the values of those "editor" controls prior to changing the selection in the `ListView`.

---

**MCVE:**

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.StringProperty;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.ListView;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

        // Simple Interface
        HBox root = new HBox(10);
        root.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        root.setPadding(new Insets(10));

        // Simple ListView
        ListView<Person> listView = new ListView<>();
        listView.getItems().setAll(
                new Person("Jack", "j@email.com"),
                new Person("Bill", "bill@email.com"),
                new Person("Diane", "dd@email.com")
        );

        // TextFields to edit values
        TextField txtName = new TextField();
        TextField txtEmail = new TextField();

        // Add controls to the root layout
        root.getChildren().addAll(
                listView,
                new VBox() {{
                    getChildren().addAll(
                            new Label("Name:"),
                            txtName,
                            new Label("Email:"),
                            txtEmail);
                }}
        );

        // Add listener to update bindings for the TextFields
        listView.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty().addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {

            // Unbind previously bound values
            if (oldValue != null) {

                // If name or email are missing, prevent the change
                if (!validate(oldValue))
                    return; // *** This is where I need help as this obviously is not correct *** //

                txtName.textProperty().unbindBidirectional(oldValue.nameProperty());
                txtEmail.textProperty().unbindBidirectional(oldValue.emailProperty());
            }

            // Bind the new values
            if (newValue != null) {
                txtName.textProperty().bindBidirectional(newValue.nameProperty());
                txtEmail.textProperty().bindBidirectional(newValue.emailProperty());

                // Refresh the ListView to show changes
                listView.refresh();
            }

        });

        // Show the stage
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root));
        primaryStage.setTitle("Sample");
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    private boolean validate(Person oldValue) {
        return !(oldValue.getName().trim().isEmpty() || oldValue.getName().trim().isEmpty());
    }
}

class Person {

    private StringProperty name = new SimpleStringProperty();
    private StringProperty email = new SimpleStringProperty();

    public Person(String name, String email) {
        this.name.set(name);
        this.email.set(email);
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name.get();
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name.set(name);
    }

    public StringProperty nameProperty() {
        return name;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email.get();
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email.set(email);
    }

    public StringProperty emailProperty() {
        return email;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return name.get();
    }
}
```

---

When the user selects a different item from the `ListView`, how do I first validate that `txtName` and `txtEmail` contain valid values?

I have followed [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39655280/javafx-how-to-cancel-combobox-selection-change) in order to prevent a selection altogether, but I can not find a way to allow the selection change (while also updating the bindings) if the values are valid.

Essentially, in this example, I want to make sure the TextFields are not empty before moving on to the new selection.

Comment: In don't have time to thoroughly analyze your problem but shouldn't `validate(oldValue)` be `validate(newValue)` instead? After all you want to validate a value change and thus the new value being set.

Comment: @Thomas - No, I want to ensure the currently-selected item has valid values (in the TextFields) before allowing the selection of a different item.

Comment: unrelated: don't use refresh!

Comment: the reason that the other answer is not working, is inversed logic in your validate: it should return !(name.isEmpty() || email.isEmpty()) Correcting that alone will not help, though - because the invalid person is already updated with the incorrect name. You need to implement additonal logic to make it valid again ... have to go now, sry

Comment: Does the question boil down to how do I validate a `TextField` content before using it ?

Comment: @c0der - Not really. The question is: how do I validate a `TextField` before I allow the `ListView` selection to change?

Comment: there is no means to disallow a selection change - period. even a custom selectionmodel will be hard to implement because the change mechanism is private API. reverting a change in a listener is ... suboptimal but might be a last straw

Comment: Kleopatra - the linked answer does implement a simple means of disallowing a selection change... It just doesn't include a way to make it conditional on other Node values.

Comment: no, it _doesnt disallow_ - it _reverts_ a selection change! implement just as in the other answer, add your own conditional and be happy. repeating: your validation logic above is _wrong_ at least as per your description: _I want to make sure the TextFields are not empty before moving on to the new selection_ - yours is doing just the contrary.

Comment: @kleopatra - good catch. I fixed the sample code to return the correct `validate()` value.

Answer (score 1):

As i know you can not consume this event from inside ChangeListener, as it`s a listener, it is notify you about already happened changes.

But you can add mouse filter, listen for a mouse clicks, validate needed data inside this event and consume it, if you`r not happy.

```
  listView.addEventFilter(MouseEvent.MOUSE_PRESSED, event -> {
        if(!validate(listView.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem())) event.consume();
    });
```

Also i believe you can implement you own MultipleSelectionModel, but this will be much more time consuming

Comment: This is promising, but will not catch if the user changes the selection using the arrow keys. Granted, I could also implement a filter for key presses, but that seems like overkill..

Comment: why. if you want to catch arrow keys it is logical you need implement filter for them also,  it is not over kill. You can store even filter realisation in an object and then just pass same object in multiple addEventListener calls, thats will reduce sources amount

Answer (score 0):

When your conditions are invalid, i think reselecting with old item will get what you require. This way you dont need to worry about filters for mouse and key events.

I changed the listener implementation to below. And it is working in your demo as expected. The only thing I am concerned is using Platform.runLater. Maybe someone can suggest me how to get without using that.

```
// Add listener to update bindings for the TextFields
        listView.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty().addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {
            boolean proceed = true;
            // Unbind previously bound values
            if (oldValue != null) {
                txtName.textProperty().unbindBidirectional(oldValue.nameProperty());
                txtEmail.textProperty().unbindBidirectional(oldValue.emailProperty());

                // If name or email are missing, prevent the change
                if (validate(oldValue)) {
                    Platform.runLater(() -> listView.getSelectionModel().select(oldValue));
                    proceed = false;
                }
            }

            // Bind the new values
            if (newValue != null && proceed) {
                txtName.textProperty().bindBidirectional(newValue.nameProperty());
                txtEmail.textProperty().bindBidirectional(newValue.emailProperty());
                // Refresh the ListView to show changes
                listView.refresh();
            }
        });
```

**Update:** Arrggh... I just noticed that my answer is almost similar to the linked answer and you already discussed that with @Kleopatra. But this will solve your issue :)

@Kleopatra : As per your comment regarding refresh(), can you please suggest a way to get the details updated in listView. I am stuck at that point.

Comment: This looks better than the linked answer to me as you do provide a way to still perform the validation. I will give this a try in the morning.

As for the "do not use refresh()" comment from Kleopatra, I have not found a valid way to update the `ListView` either, and have never seen an explanation for why calling `refresh()` should be avoided...

Comment: if the update doesn't happen without the refresh, the setup is wrong. the simple example is just working fine without, if not configure the list items with an extractor

Comment: This actually causes a strange situation where the selection will keep bouncing back and forth between the oldValue and the newValue.

Comment: I am not clear what you mean by bouncing back and forth. Do you mean it is going in loop with the selection between the two cells? The listener is called only two times. One when you try to select another cell and other when it forces to select the old cell (if invalid).

Answer (score 0):

This is *not* an answer to the original question just a code snippet too long for a comment.

Re: refresh();

*Why not use it*: it's absolute emergency api, a crude hook to force an update if there is no way whatever to make the automagics of FX properties do their work. Can't be repeated often enough: don't don't don't - if a seem to need it, there's something wrong with your data setup. That's a fact, always (as in 99.9999999%)

*How to avoid*: fix your data setup, make sure notifications are sent as expected. A frequent reason is that properties of items in a list are changed. By default, the observableList does not listen for internal updates to its items so can't notify its own listener, you have to explicitly configure it to listen and fire update events - done by providing an extractor.

Code snippet:

```
ObservableList<Person> persons = FXCollections.observableArrayList(
        p -> new Observable[]{p.nameProperty(), p.emailProperty()});
persons.setAll(new Person("Jack", "j@email.com"),
        new Person("Bill", "bill@email.com"),
        new Person("Diane", "dd@email.com"));

// Simple ListView
ListView<Person> listView = new ListView<>(persons);
```

Comment: Thanks for the clarification @kleopatra. Actually I already tried checking with extractor and it is no success. From your code snippet I then realised that i am doing 
listView.getItems().setAll(persons)

instead of 
listView.setItems(persons). With the later, it is indeed updating the cell instantly.